# How many Postgres database we need to implement version 16 bidirectional replication?

Tags: postgresql

Generally, for HA we keep everything in odd numbers. Do we need 3 or just 2 Postgres db to implement bi-directional replication in Postgres 16?

Comment: 1) The community version of Postgres does not have bi-directional replication, assuming you mean master <--> master. If you mean something else or are using a Postgres fork you need to add that information to your question. 2) Also this is really a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/.